# Verb chaining and tenses: "To where we've been before" vs. "To where we'd been before" in a poem by Brodsky

Tags: past-tense, poetry

Here is a piece by Brodsky

> I wish you were here, dear,
>   I wish you were here.
>   I wish we were in my car,
>   and you'd shift the gear.
>   we'd find ourselves elsewhere,
>   on an unknown shore.
>   Or else we'd repair
>   To where we've been before.

The last two lines have drawn my attention. Shouldn't it be "or else we'd repair to where we had been before"?

([A Song](http://www.poemhunter.com/best-poems/joseph-brodsky/a-song-3/))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either one can be "correct," depending on the intention of the author. Brodsky chose the perfect, I suspect, because that is how the thought would be rendered in natural speech. It implies that the "being" in that familiar setting is still going on, or may continue. The pluperfect would imply that he and his dear are finished, for now, with that "being." But beware: applying "rules of grammar" to poetry is like trying to cut a paper doll with a pair of pliers.